# $(...).function is not a function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I know this issue has been posted in previous posts but nothing helped me and it's driving me crazy, even more I'm sure the answer is pretty simple, but I'm really new to javascript

I'm trying to integrate this raptor-konami-code from there: http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-raptorize

so I c/p all the content in the folder of my html file, I got the src folders right in my `head`, but I keep getting this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).raptorize is not a function
```

And I really don't know why. Here is my head content, which is the strictly same (except the title page) of the one in the sample html file provided in the plugin folder and which works!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />    
    <title>Personnal Website</title>
    <!-- jQuery: Grab Google CDN jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- The raptorize file  -->
    <script src="jquery.raptorize.1.0.js"></script>

    <!-- For the button version -->


    <!-- For the Konami Code version -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.button').raptorize({
          'enterOn' : 'konami-code'
        });
      });
    </script>

    <!-- For the Timer version -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('.button').raptorize({
'enterOn' : 'timer',
'delayTime' : 2000
});
});
</script>   
-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo-styles.css" />

  </head>
```

the source code of jquery.raptorize.1.0.js can be viewed here:

http://zurb.com/playground/uploads/upload/upload/254/jquery.raptorize.js

I've tried a lot of things, like changing de $ for jQuery, change (document).load to (document).ready, but nothing works I still get this error in the console and I don't why.. Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try window ready instead of load

Comment: @244an — Why? In the unlikely event that it is a problem with the timing of the binding of the method to the jQuery object, trying to access it **sooner** isn't going to help.

Comment: Oups, I meant document ready

Comment: Can you show a live site?

Comment: @244an — My point stands.

Comment: Guess it has something to do with raptorize not getting initialized.

Comment: @damouf check your browser's network tab and make sure the raptorize script loaded properly.

Comment: @damouf - jquery.raptorize.1.0.js on your site (if present) is likely not in the same folder as the page you are trying to use it in.

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/gonezu/1/edit?html,output). Almost certainly you just got the URL to your .js file wrong. If it isn't that, then it is probably a permissions problem. The Net tab should reveal what.

Comment: @Quentin, either it works or not, why not just test it?

Comment: @244an Because if you have even elementary understanding of what those functions do and how jQuery plugins work it should be obvious that it won't help.

Comment: Guess it is better to wait for the OP who is long lost in his dreams after posting this question, @Quentin! `:P`

Comment: @244an Trial and error programming should be avoided if possible. Work to understand _why_ you write the code you write.

Comment: Hi everyone, sorry for the wait, first time I post here and I've never seen such quickly answers on any forums!!!!! 

So according to the network tab (tool that I didn't know thanks!) the file is correctly loaded (from cache but I dont think it's a problem), and either on my live version or on local I'm still getting the error. 

@PraveenKumar live version can be seen here, it's a school project: 

http://sitewebperso.alwaysdata.net/


thanks everyone for your comments!

Comment: @Quentin wht do you mean by permission problem?

Comment: @244 As I said, I've already tried ready instead of load

Comment: ok damouf, so you waisted 30 seconds of your life and shown that you (like me) don't "have even elementary understanding of what those functions do and how jQuery plugins work", according to @Juhana :)

Comment: @damouf — That the server might be returning a 403 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, line number: `135`, please remove the unnecessary re-initialization of jQuery 1.8.2:

```
<!--====================================end demo wrapper================================================-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

This removes the old jQuery and rewrites it with the new one. If you need, you can do something like this:

```
$jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

This preserves everything else, leaving the `$` to work for you. And yes, as I said you in my previous comment, please use `$(document).ready()` event instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').raptorize({
        'enterOn' : 'konami-code'
    });
});
```

Comment: omg I was pretty sure it was something very obvious... I totally forgot that line that was there for a previous purpose... it work now! thanks a lot... very newbish problem :)

Comment: @damouf Glad it helped you.

Comment: @damouf, Eh? This is the same solution that I wrote in my answer. And mine got downvotes. I don't understand that.

Comment: The downvotes doesn't matter, they can be there, but sometimes it would be good to know why you get them. Especially in this case.

Comment: @244an If you have enough rep to see the deleted answers, my first answer too got downvoted and I know it was by Quentin for a valid reason. :(

Comment: @244an and Praveen, sorry for that, I upvoted both your answers... some people didnt seem to like them though they actually solved my problem... :/

Comment: @damouf Don't worry buddy. Everything is sorted.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, may I ask why my answer was deleted? It would be good to know the reason so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: @244an Man, that's what I am saying. Our answers are almost the same. I **don't** know why you were downvoted!

Comment: Just wanna to know why it was deleted, not why it was downvoted, it's deleted by you and some other. My answer was there almost 2 hours before yours. It's kind of frustrating when you spend time trying to solve some others problem.